# dynamic routing in ui-router in angularjs and change the url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I write an application with angularjs and use ui router for dynamic routing , my app has a page for display list of news and when click on a news , Explanation of the news is showing
for example if I have a news with `id=3` when i click on link of this news the url change to `news/3` and when click on a news with `id=5` url change to `news/4` but i want to change url to `news/subnews/third` or `news/subnews/fifth`
my piece of code for change url and content is like this

```
.state('news', {
            abstract:true ,
            url: "/news",
            templateUrl: "views/news/news.html",


        })
         .state('news.showAll', {

            url: "",
            templateUrl: "views/news/showAllNews.html",


        })
    .state( 'news.detail',{
                url:"/:newsId",
                templateUrl: "views/news/tmpShowDet.html",
                 controller:"newsShowing",
                    resolve:{
                            newsId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,newsId){
                            return $stateParams.newsId;
                                    }]
                        }



            })
```

what is the true way for display like `news/subnews/....`

Answer (score 0):

How many 'subnews' do you want?

Translating numbers to words can get a little tricky, and spoken-language specific. Example: at 'subnews/101' do you want 'subnews/onehundredandone or subnews/onehundredandfirst or subnews/oneohone'.

I would recommend, if you only have a few subnews possibilities, going by categories.In that case, it seems you already know how to implement, or have access to the [documentation for UrlRouteProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider).

If you have many subnews, I would leave the parameter as an integer, which is relatively spoken-language agnostic. You can always mask it or build a lookup table, etc if you don't want it displayed.

Speaking of which, if you still want to change the integer to a word, just use a lookup, and the url docs.

Cheers, [bro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3955466/m-hadadi)